# Pass props value to this.state but get undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I need to pass props to my initial state, but when I get `undefined` for the final result. 
Consider code below:

```
constructor (props){
        super(props);
        const supplier_id = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('id'));
        this.state ={
            id: props.items_id,        // get the items_id from props
            supplier_id: supplier_id,
            item_name:'',
            item_shortDes: '',
            item_longDes: '',
            price: '',
            terms_agreement: '',
            Location: '',
            selectedFile: null,
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this);
      }

      updateItem(){

        const itemData = this.state
        const selectedFile = this.state.selectedFile
        console.log(itemData)    

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('json', JSON.stringify(itemData))
        formData.append('itemFile', selectedFile) 

        fetch(`http://localhost:9000.com/api/item/submit`,  //call api here
        {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        })

      }
```

But I can see my items_id inside the render()

```
render() {
        const { items_id } = this.props;
        console.log(items_id) //i can get my items id here, but why cannot get it on this.state
     return (
         ...
     )
}
```

My console result here

[image]

id was show `undefined` here

Comment: Does `props.id` come from some asynchronous call, maybe from an API?

Comment: @BrianThompson yes, it comes from an API.

Comment: Thats going to be your problem then most likely. The constructor is only called one time in the component lifecycle. If the API hasn't responded by the time your component is rendered, you've missed your chance to use it in the constructor.

Comment: You have a few options. Delay rendering of the component until your API has responded.  Re-update state in a lifecycle method (maybe componentDidUpdate).